# How to fix null parameters when emitting to async listeners in node.js's event library?

Tags: node.js, events

I have three js classes: my event object class that is being exported, one class that has the emit function, the other class is the listeners in the constructor. I have three listeners that are using the `setImmediate()` to make it async. The first listener is able to get the parameter correctly, but not the other two.

I tried printing it out before the `setImmediate()` callback, and I was able to see the correct parameters.

```
bus.on('event', (input) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
         function(input); //parameter are not null here
    });
}, this);
bus.on('event', (input) => {
    //console.log(input) when printing the input here, I can see the values
    setImmediate(() => {
         function2(input); //null
    });
}, this);
bus.on('event', (input) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
         function3(input);
    });
}, this);
```

I except the `input` to be `[e1, e2, e3`, but the actual output is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `input` is good when you enter the event handler, but not after `setImmediate()`, then something else in your code must be changing the array before you're able to use it.  This is a danger of passing around a mutable object in asynchronous code.

To protect yourself from that, you can make a copy of the array so that nobody else can change it.

```
bus.on('event', (input) => {
    // make copy of input so nobody else will change it
    let inputCopy = input.slice();
    setImmediate(() => {
         function2(inputCopy);
    });
}, this);
```

Note: If your array contains objects and those objects themselves might be getting changed by someone else, then the copy above won't protect you against that.

You could also avoid this issue by not using `setImmediate()` here and just processing the array synchronously.